# MySQL: Wrong result of query using left join

Tags: mysql, left-join

I faced the problem described here: https://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/ (gaps when grouping the result of SUM or COUNT by date). My first attempt for a solution was this, query 1:

```
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(st.vd, '%Y-%m-%d') as d,
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN st.vd IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END
    ) AS nrvisits
  FROM
    (
      SELECT v.visit_date vd
      FROM `temp_dates_2` t
      LEFT JOIN `visits` v ON DATE(v.visit_date) = DATE(t.t_date)
      ORDER BY t.t_date
    ) as st
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d
```

(temp_dates_2 contains a unique list of dates). I simplified it, query 2:

```
  SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(td.t_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as d,
      (SELECT COUNT(1)
        FROM visits as v
        WHERE DATE(v.visit_date) = DATE(td.t_date)
      ) as nrvisits
  FROM temp_dates_2 td
  GROUP BY d
  ORDER BY d
```

Both queries are running without syntax or runtime errors but the results are different: The values provided by query 1 are much larger. I used a very simple query for a single date in order to clarify:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM visits WHERE DATE_FORMAT(visit_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2021-01-21'
```

It provided the same result as query 2.
My question is: Why does query 1 provide a wrong result? I suspect that the result of the subquery with an inner join returns multiple records for the same visit.
Update: sql dumps of the tables: https://webentwicklung.ulrichbangert.de/temp_dates_2.sql https://webentwicklung.ulrichbangert.de/visits.sql

Comment: Some sample data and expected result would help us understand better the problem

Comment: Can simplify it further: `SELECT t.t_date, COUNT(v.primarykeycolumn)
      FROM temp_dates_2 t
      LEFT JOIN visits v ON DATE(v.visit_date) = t.t_date
      GROUP BY t.t_date`

Comment: ps i think Q1 is wrong, because sometimes st.vd is null and this can be any number of dates that didn't match (if you had temp dates of 25-12-2000 and 26-12-2000 then there are no visits on those dates because it's closed for xmas but they both become null an end up merged

Comment: @caius-jard That's brilliant, your query works like a charm. However I would like to understand why query 1 does not. Yet I do not understand your explanation as query 1 contains this:

    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN st.vd IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END
    )

which should include 0 in the sum when there is no visit?

Comment: Order by in a subquery without top/limit does nothing. PS Don't ask us why the queries return what they do, it's because the language is defined that way, don't ask for yet another presentation of the language. Say why you think they should be the same & find the 1st subexpression that doesn't return what you expect, say what you expect & why, both with reference to authoritative documentation. PS Put everything needed to ask your question in the post. [ask] [help] [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling out my comment some more. I suggested this:

```
SELECT 
  t.t_date, 
  COUNT(v.primarykeycolumn)      
FROM 
  temp_dates_2 t       
  LEFT JOIN visits v ON DATE(v.visit_date) = t.t_date       
GROUP BY t.t_date
```

Based on the assumption that temp_dates_2 contains only DATEs (so there isn't a need to call DATE() on them), and perhaps v.visit_date contains a time too, and DATE() is stripping that off

I also suggested that q1 has a bug in that the subquery selects the visit date, which might cause dates to merge/get lost. Here's an example:

```
Visits
2020-12-24 12:34:56 --(visit on christmas eve - shop still open
2020-12-24 23:45:00 --(visit on christmas eve - shop still open
                    --(no visit on christmas day - shop closed)
                    --(no visit on boxing day - shop closed)
2020-12-27 12:34:56 --(visit - shop reopen)

temp_dates_2
2020-12-24 
2020-12-25 
2020-12-26 
2020-12-27
```

Result of left join subquery in your Q1 (removed irrelevant orderby):

```
  SELECT v.visit_date vd
  FROM `temp_dates_2` t
  LEFT JOIN `visits` v ON DATE(v.visit_date) = DATE(t.t_date)

2020-12-24 --(visit on christmas eve - shop still open
2020-12-24 --(visit on christmas eve - shop still open
NULL       --(no visit on christmas day - shop closed)
NULL       --(no visit on boxing day - shop closed)
2020-12-27 --(visit - shop reopen)
```

Then q1 groups, sums and formats etc, resulting in:

```
Date        Count
2020-12-24  2
NULL        0
2020-12-27  1
```

Really, it's not much different to a basic `SELECT date(visit_date), count(*) FROM visits GROUP BY date(visit_date)` except it has this useless NULL that represents the merging of xmas day and boxing day, and 0 count. Really what you seemed to be wanting was a:

```
2020-12-24  2 --(visits on christmas eve - shop still open
2020-12-25  0 --(no visit on christmas day - shop closed)
2020-12-26  0 --(no visit on boxing day - shop closed)
2020-12-27  1
```

Given by my first query; it uses the fact that COUNT() does not count nulls, and by counting either a column that participated in the LEFT JOIN or by counting a primary key column, we can be sure that NULL only happens in that kind of column because "the join failed; no matching row found in right hand table" and not because "the data naturally contained a null in the row"

For example:

```
temp_dates left join visits:

tempdate    visitdate   visitpk  vistorcomment
2020-12-24  2021-12-24  1        null
2020-12-25  null        null
2020-12-26  null        null
2020-12-27  2021-12-27  2        "nice place"
```

We should COUNT() either `visitpk` (the primary key can never be null) or `visitdate` (it will be null if the join failed), we should never COUNT comment, because it's sometimes null naturally (visitor left no comment). If we used visitorcomment as the count it would ditort the figures as it means "visit occurred and visitor left a comment"

---

All this doesn't answer "why are my figures larger in X than Y" but that cannot be answered without a working example; create a fiddle that replicates it and I'll tell you. I cannot currently see any reason from the data stated why q1's numbers would be larger - you assert temp_dates are unique so a cartesian explosion should not occur, and you seem to be using date datatypes so mixing up of dd/mm and m/dd shoudn't be occurrring, but I can see a bug in how you're treating the data/the result is not what you want

This was an answer to explain how to get the result you want, why it works, and have a simpler query..

Comment: Hi Casius Jard, thanks for this detailed explanation! As requested I tried to setup a working example on sqlfiddle and - OMG; so silly: There were multiple entries in the table temp_dates_2. The reason was that this table is created dynamically by a stored procedure and this procedure created the table if not exists but didn't empty it if exists. After having fixed this all the queries are returning the same results. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion and inconvenience!

Comment: That'd explain it ;) - in the case of a join, two same dates on the temp table (e.g. 24-dec-2020 joining to two visits on the right would result in 1 row that declared 4 visits, but without the join i.e. doing as the `SELECT date, (SELECT count WHERE date = date) FROM ..` would result in two rows that declared 2 visits.. :)